# javascript event before scroll redraw?

Tags: javascript, events

I have a javascript function on the onscoll event to change a div's style.

The problem is that most browsers draw the div after a scoll but *before* the onscoll event fires, so you end up with 1 or 2 frames where the div has the old style but the viewport is at the new scroll position. This can cause ugly flickering.

How do you prevent this?

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to do exactly what you are asking.  Perhaps if you provide some details on what you are doing people may have some suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: please create a jsfiddle

Comment: Watch out for browser dependencies--you'll need to test on all of your supported browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346327/force-javascript-to-run-before-browser-redraw-jsfiddle-examle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe set the body to overflow:hidden to start, and change it to overflow:auto once the first onscroll fires.