# Force javascript to run *before* browser redraw (jsFiddle example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am building a little web based application using an HTML table. One unusual property of this table is that it has fixed top row and left column (similar to excel). I accomplished this using a little jQuery and CSS.

The problem is, the jQuery event that triggers my code is the $(window).scroll event, and evidently most browsers (Chrome and IE) redraw the page before the code that is called by this event is finished running. As a result, the left column and top row take a split second to "catch up" to the rest of the table.

I've provided a [stripped down jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/55/) in order to show you my problem. **Note:** The lag isn't very noticeable when the table is so small and (relatively speaking) empty of content. Nevertheless, it is there (assuming you aren't using firefox). Is there any way to get rid of this lag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea, but maybe worth considering: You could try using `requestAnimationFrame` as described in [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/) (or in a similar way). That might smooth out the update/"lag" issues.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the way raf works, but it seems like that wouldn't completely solve my problem, since my problem involves frames being drawn too soon. Is that right? Or is there something I'm not getting?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` allows you to issue commands just before a repaint. So whatever you change in requestAnimationFrame will show in the next repaint. It's a callback that is invoked by the browser when it's about to draw the webpage. Your problem is most likely due to calling syncHeadColumns just after the scroll was painted (what you suspect) or due to too many scroll callbacks beeing issued - that is more than 1 event per frame. This causes lag in visual updates (personally I believe this is more likely). In any case: I believe `requestAnimationFrame` should be able to help with both.

Comment: What I would try is call `syncHeadColumns` from `requestAnimationFrame` instead from the scroll event. That should reduce the amount of calls to `syncHeadColumns` but keep the headers smoothly in position. Also, you might want to check how repaint and reflow behavior works in browsers, if you're not into that yet. There are certain element and css attributes that cause a reflow when they are changed. This should not be the case for most attributes on `position:fixed` elements, but maybe I am missing something in your code that causes reflows.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining that! It looks feasible and I might give it a shot.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/124/) and in my project. It works initially, but if you mess with the page a little (change some of the row heights using the buttons, ect.) it starts to slow *way* down. Any idea why it would be doing that?

Comment: Hm.. not really. You should try to use some of the tools provided through most webbrowser's developer tools, like Chrome's timeline and profiling functions. Maybe they can help you figuring out where your browser spends his time. Maybe that'll help you improve your code. Just from my head though I have no further ideas.

Comment: Any idea what is different in this example?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515323/change-elements-css-immediately-on-scroll-event

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get this to work with either the scroll event or with requestAnimationFrame. What I ended up doing is attaching to the mousewheel event, which fires before scrolling and rendering has happend. If the scroll event is going downward, I can apply the appropriate class in time for rendering.

Comment: Interesting! +1 for sharing. Thanks.