# A better implementation of Excel style HTML table with fixed top row AND left column? (jsFiddle example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a pretty simple question: Is there a more efficient way to implement a large table with fixed rows and columns than this [stripped down jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aHKU5/55/) I created, *or* is there a better way to write the few lines of jQuery that power it?

Before anyone jumps on me for posting a question that's similar to others out there, let me explain myself. I realize there are multiple plugins that accomplish similar effects to my example above. However, none of them (that I could find) provide the flexibility and functionality that I require.

Here are a few caveats that my implementation must support:

- Must have the ability to hide and unhide entire rows
- Must support cells of a dynamic height
- Should (ideally) use the browser's scrollbars to navigate the table
- Must be *fast* in order to support large tables
- **The table must be able to be dynamically generated with knockoutjs**

The main problem I see with my implementation is that it lags in Chrome and IE. It's hard to notice with the table I provide in the example, but the left column and top row take a moment to "catch up" to the rest of the table. This problem becomes much more pronounced when the table is large and has other javascript running in the background as well.

**So, is there a better way to implement this given my caveats?**

Comment: Isn't this question virtually the same as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346327/force-javascript-to-run-before-browser-redraw-jsfiddle-examle)?

Comment: My previous question used the same example, and I'm still trying to figure out ways to improve it, but other than that, no. I was looking for a specific fix to my issue using js then. This question is more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get a performance increase by changing this:

```
var offset = $(this).next().offset();
        $(this).offset(offset);
        $(this).css('left', '0');
        $(this).height($(this).next().height());
```

To this:

```
        var $this = $(this)
        var offset = $this.next().offset();
        $this.offset(offset);
        $this.css('left', '0');
        $this.height($this.next().height());
```

Using a variable is faster than continuously wrapping the same object over and over.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Steve. I'm choosing your answer because it's the best one I got.

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin is perfect for your request: http://www.jtable.org/Demo

Comment: Is it? It doesn't look like it supports excel-style fixed head row and left column, which is what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: I loved jTable,  this looks a lot fresh than common grids like dataTables,  though performance issues may be fixed on this to bring at par with others. btw,  I was able to freeze <thead> with a little JS/jQuery.  one thing i hate about filters is the need for clicking a button.. it's not 2008..