# change css on scroll event w/ requestAnimation Frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, requestanimationframe

I want to change the background color of in-viewport elements (using `overflow: scroll`)

So here was my first attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/2YeZG/

As you see, there is a brief flicker of the previous color before the new color is painted.  Others have [had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966971/javascript-event-before-scroll-redraw) similar [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346327/force-javascript-to-run-before-browser-redraw-jsfiddle-examle).

Following the [HTML5 rocks instructions](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/#an-example), I tried to introduce `requestAnimationFrame` to fix this problem to no avail:

http://jsfiddle.net/RETbF/

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Here is a simpler example showing the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/HJ9ng/

---

Filed bug with Chromium here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=151880

Comment: it definitely flickers in chrome, this could be a browser implementation issue... even in the demo in the page you linked, you see some flickering even on their optimized page.

Comment: flickers for me in chrome, but if i drag really slowly they all change as expected, seems to just skip some elements if you scroll fast.

Comment: @Neil yes, when you scroll fast is when it happens.  but that is what i am trying prevent w/ requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 1):

if it is only the background color, well why don't you just change the parent background color to red and once it scroll just change it to pink?

I change your CSS to that

```
#dad
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color:red;
}​
```

I remove some of you Jquery and change it to this

```
dad.bind('scroll', function() {
    dad.css('background-color', 'pink');
});
```

And I remove this line

```
iChild.css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

But is the Red color it is important that won't work for sure  http://jsfiddle.net/2YeZG/5/

Comment: Thank you, but the change to red is just to make it easy to see the problem.  I want to change each iChild to a different color.

Comment: When do you need to have it change? Soon as you start scrolling or once they are out the of screen? What I mean is user need to scroll up to see the differente color as it already benn seen.

Comment: I need just-in-time as-soon-as-in-view per child CSS updates.

Comment: Children can change multiple times...  They are like chameleons

Comment: Will all be the same color let said when they are at some height? EX: the 2 on top, blue, 5 in middle pink, 2 at bottom yellow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16983/discussion-between-manuel-choucino-and-jedierikb)

Answer (score 0):

I like Manuel's Solution.
But even though I don't get what you're exactly trying to do, I want to point out a few things.
In your fiddle code, I saw that you included Paul Irish's Shim for requestAnimationFrame.
But you never use it.
 (It's basically a reliable setTimeOut, nothing else) it's from frame based animations.)

So since you just want to change some CSS properties, I don't see why you would need it. Even if you want transitions, you should rely on CSS transitions.

Other than that your code could look something like

```
dad.bind('scroll', function() {
  dad.css('background-color', 'pink');
  eachElemNameHere.css('background-color','randomColor');
});
```

Also you should ideally not use something like that if you can help it. You should just add and remove class names and add all these properties in your CSS. Makes it work faster.

Also, again I don't quite get it, but you could use the jQuery function to find out each elements' position from the top to have better control.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you only change the background color of the elements which **have already been scrolled into view**. Your code expects that the browser waits for your code to handle the scroll event before the browser redraws its view. This is most probably not a guarantee given by the HTML spec. That's why it flickers.

What you should do instead is to change the elements which **are going to be scrolled into view**. This is related to *off screen rendering* or *double buffering* as it is called in computer games programming. You build your scene off screen and copy the finished scene to the visible frame buffer.

I modified your first JSFiddle to include a multiplier for the height of the scroll area: http://jsfiddle.net/2YeZG/13/.

```
dad.bind('scroll', function() {
    // new: query multiplier from input field (for demonstration only) and print message
    var multiplier = +($("#multiplier")[0].value);
    $("#message")[0].innerHTML=(multiplier*100)-100 + "% of screen rendering";

    // your original code
    var newScrollY = newScrollY = dad.scrollTop();
    var isForward = newScrollY > oldScrollY;
    var minVal = bSearch(bots, newScrollY, true);

    // new: expand covered height by the given multiplier
    //      multiplier = 1 is similar to your code
    //      multiplier = 2 would be complete off screen rendering
    var newScrollYHt = newScrollY + multiplier * dadHeight;

    // your original code (continued)
    var maxVal;
    for (maxVal = minVal; maxVal < botsLen; maxVal++) {
        var nxtTopSide = tops[maxVal];
        if (nxtTopSide >= newScrollYHt) {
            break;
        }
    }
    maxVal = Math.min(maxVal, botsLen);
    $(dadKids.slice(minVal, maxVal)).css('background', 'pink');
});
```

Your code had a multiplier of 1, meaning that you update the elements which are currently visible (100% of scroll area height). If you set the multiplier to 2, you get complete off screen updates for all your elements. The browser updates enough elements to the new background color so that even a 100% scroll would show updated elements. Since the browser seldom scrolls 100% of the area in one step (depends of the operating system and the scroll method!), it may be sufficient to reduce the multiplier to e.g. 1.5 (meaning 50% off screen rendering). On my machine (Google Chrome, Mac OS X with touch pad) I cannot produce any flicker if the multiplier is 1.7 or above.

BTW: If you do something more complicated than just changing the background color, you should not do it again and again. Instead you should check whether the element has already been updated and perform the change only afterwards.

Comment: if using javascript to jump the scrollbar to an arbitrary location in the div, this solution will, unfortunately, not work.